# Postfix, sender_bcc - send copy on multiple adress

Tags: postfix, pcre

I have `sender_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/conf/sender_bcc` in my postfix
in this file I have rules such as

```
/foo@bar.tld/       bcchere@bar.tld
```

Now i need to send blind copy to more than one email.
I tried use whitespace and comma as delimeter, but it did not work. 
What is the solution here? Thank you.

**EDIT:** 
The solution is (thx dynax60) to send copy to alias in sender_bcc_maps file. 
And then set this alias with desired addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

`sender_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc`

- in /etc/postfix/sender_bcc:

`/foo@bar.tld/       bcc_duplicator@bar.tld`

- in $virtual_alias_maps:

`bcc_duplicator@bar.tld bcc1@bar.tld, bcc2@bar.tld, bcc3@bar.tld`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in main.cf:

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/bcc
```

Content of bcc file is:

```
user1@domain.tld bigbro@domain.tld
user2@domain.tld bigbro@domain.tld
user3@domain.tld bigbro@domain.tld
```

Don't forget postmap bcc under /usr/local/etc/postfix/.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to not solve my problem. I need something like
`user@domain.tld bigbro1@domain.tld, bigbro2@domain.tld`

Comment: why don't you use alias for this way? bigbro@ could be an alias to target users :)

Comment: Clever.I did not realize that i can do that. I will try it.